# Quill Editor: Restricted Editing based on tags/classes

Tags: quill

I have a scenario where I would like to give users a semi-editable template such as

```
<p>Name: <span class="editable"></span></p>
```

or

```
<div>
    <p>Non editable content</p>
    <h2>Some editable content</h2>
    <h3>Some more editable content</h3>
</div>
```

Where specific tags or classes can either be specifically denied or allowed from editing. Additionally, these classes or tags can not overlap each other in selection (in the example, h2 and h3 can not be both selected).

Considering I've only modified Quill a small amount I'm not totally sure of the best way to accomplish this or if there is even a good way at all.