# Atomic Text Blot in Quill

Tags: quill

Let's say I want to have an `AtomicText` blot that is similar to the default `Link` blot but is immutable and can only be removed as a whole. More specifically:

- The cursor can be between the characters of `AtomicText`.
- It is possible to select parts of `AtomicText`.
- Deleting at least one character of `AtomicText` leads to the deletion of the whole `AtomicText`.
- Adding characters to `AtomicText` is not possible once it has been created. Neither via keyboard events nor via copy and paste.

My idea was to make `AtomicText` extend from the `Embed` blot. In that case, the whole `AtomicText` blot is deleted when the cursor is right to its last character and backspace is pressed. But other operations do not work as expected. I assume I need to override some of the `Blot` methods to achieve the correct behavior but I am a bit at loss here.

Another idea is to listen to `text-change` events, determine if the cursor is inside an `AtomicText` blot and act accordingly. E.g., when pressing backspace, find the start and end position of the current `AtomicText` blot and remove all characters between these indexes. This seems to be a fragile approach.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Similar questions/requests are the following:

- [How to make non selectable embed custom format in quilljs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40159839/how-to-make-non-selectable-embed-custom-format-in-quilljs)
- [How to add a non editable tag to content in Quill editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39601992/how-to-add-a-non-editable-tag-to-content-in-quill-editor)
- [Quill Editor: Restricted Editing based on tags/classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36991966/quill-editor-restricted-editing-based-on-tags-classes)

Comment: What other operations do not work as expected?

Comment: For example, I can still add characters to an AtomicText blot. I experimented more and tried to set contentEditable=false for the node in the blot definition. This didn't work but creating an artificial child node with contentEditable=false came closer but still not close enough. It seems even if you inherit from Embed but your node has text, this text is handled like a normal Text blot so you can still add characters to it.

Comment: Here's a similar request for ProseMirror ('Locked nodes'): https://discuss.prosemirror.net/t/locked-nodes/448/1

Comment: If you want to prevent typing you need it to be contenteditable=false

Comment: I remember trying that (see my second comment above). But it lead to seemingly broken interactions with the cursor position and trying to delete the blot. For example, I could put the cursor in the middle of the blot and pressing backspace just put the cursor at the beginning of the blot. That's why I assumed I need to override other Blot methods with custom behavior but didn't understand how to do it right.

Answer (score 3):

I my experience setting `contenteditable` false is problematic. If you position the `AtomicText` blot at the end of the document you will not be able to append to it. Additionally, moving the cursor over the `AtomicText` positioned at the end will blur the editor.

I experienced a similar issue with a footnote blot. It's a `sup` tag that contains `[\d+]` and we don't want editors to modify the footnote but we do want them to be able to seamlessly move the cursor through them.

I have experimented with two other options in addition to the `text-change` listener mentioned by the OP. The first option is to attempt to position the cursor (via `setSelection`) in front or behind using `selection-change` event listeners. I found this to be problematic because it's possible to sneak characters in before the selection change event fires. I'm also not a fan of this approach because it causes the cursor to jump across the footnote. YMMV

Another option is to intercept keyboard input. You can add a keyboard listener (I used KeyboardJS) in a module that's initialized with quill. If the current selection is "inside" of your atomic text you can stop the input from proceeding to quill using `e.preventDefault()`. With this approach you'll also have to provide custom keyboard handlers in your quill configuration to override tab, enter, and possibly delete. Tabs are more of a challenge because there's a default tab handler provided by quill that takes precedence unless you override it. Within the custom handler you'll have to detect if the `context` is within your `AtomicText`. The `context` object will contain contain a `format` map that contains `atomictext` (your blot name) if it's in the context of `AtomicText`.

Note that if the user positions the cursor adjacent to your `AtomicText`, then from quill's perspective that's in the context of `AtomicText`. Our solution to that problem for input is to insert a zero width non breaking space, then allow the keyboard input to proceed. That "breaks" the cursor out of the `AtomicText` blot allowing insertion to proceed as expected. We then strip those characters out of the resulting HTML before saving the text.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

In the blot create(value) function, add this:

```
node.setAttribute('contenteditable', false);
```